# google calendar api - change web_hook address for an existing push notification channel

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

Our site has a calendar sync feature with *google calendar* using *google calendar api*, and their *push notifications* service. so far so good, users are happy with the feature. and we're happy they're happy:)

Recently we decided to add a sub domain to the server handling google notifications (for none related reasons)
so it is changing from http://example.com to http://api.example.com.

**THE PROBLEM**  we cant find a way to replace the domain address for the existing users channels.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks.

PS - i'm aware of the security issue, after all the users authorized http://example.com and not http://api.example.com. but still we need to free http://example.com for other matters.

Comment: I think you are going to have to stop the original one and start a new one. I dont think there is anyway to updated it.  Its actually documented that its not possible to renew them so that would make me think its not possible to update them at all https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#renewing-notification-channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to stop the original one and start a new one. I dont think there is anyway to updated it. Its actually documented that its not possible to renew them so that would make me think its not possible to update them at all [Renewing notification channels.](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#renewing-notification-channels)

Comment: you are correct! the api allows stopping the channel and starting a new one with a new notification url address.